# Combining String and Integers in a single variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to combine them in PHP. But I get an integer output everytime.

Example
Expected Output:
**Input**:
aabbbc

**Output**:
2a3bc

Reality:
**Output**: 14

This is my code:

```
  $string = str_split($s);

  for($i=0;$i<count($string);$i++){
    $counter = substr_count($s,$string[$i]);
    $stringConverted += $counter . "" .  $string[$i];
    }
  return $stringConverted;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP**

Replace

```
$stringConverted += $counter . "" .  $string[$i]
```

with

```
$stringConverted .= $counter . "" .  $string[$i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use from .= instead of +=

```
$stringConverted .= $counter . "" .  $string[$i];
```